Why does my LXC have routes to 192.x.x.x subnet?
# route -v
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         RT-00904C0FF018 0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-55985fc83fa9
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-4a2e674be385
172.20.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-c4a5411407dd
172.21.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-7eb7fa74a326
172.22.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-3b304b8d2b9f
172.23.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-519d33f42172
172.24.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-10bfee6d9dcb
172.25.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-5f628b8f8682
172.26.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-d7fcffbb970a
172.27.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-4b57aa2459c5
172.28.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-a4759ccfc8c4
172.29.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-fa55d2bd337d
172.30.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-f7574a62a5c4
172.31.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-45084db52c51
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-65a630f9019d
192.168.16.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-5aa5d76d0c7a
192.168.32.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-e0d66f2d6753
192.168.48.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-beb580b505a2
192.168.214.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1024   0        0 eth0
RT-00904C0FF018 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    1024   0        0 eth0


I have an LXC with a bunch of docker containers running
I see many 172.x.x.x and assume they belong to some of the containers
What I can't quite figure out is why there are 192.x.x.x as well
Why did it jump from 172.x to 192.x?

My problem is, I have an actual server on 192.168.9.111 and I can't reach it because of these routes. Any ideas?

Please [edit] your question and add details how you configured the network of your containers.

Take a look at the answers at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64679/usage-of-192-168-xxx-172-xxx-and-10-xxx-in-private-networks and  https://superuser.com/questions/369617/what-do-the-different-formats-for-network-addresses-indicate

There are three Private IPv4 Address Spaces:

10.0.0.0/8 (10.0.0.1 - 10.255.255.254 usable if the full /8 is used).
172.16.0.0/12 (172.16.0.1 - 172.31.255.254 usable if the full /12 is used).
192.168.0.0/16 (192.168.0.1 - 192.168.255.254 usable if full /16 is used)

You have numerous bridges on your computer.  What is creating or using those bridges I am unsure (probably Docker), but you've already used all IP subnets of the 172.16.0.0/12 IP space in a total of 16 /24 networks.
Your main network that your computer is connected to is 192.168.214.0/24.  That is independent of your bridges and their routes.  The additional 192.168.X.0/24 ranges (where X is a number between 0 and 255) are simply new bridges and networks (probably Docker networks created for different compose projects or individual containers) created in the 192.168 range space for additional Docker networks.
Those routes only exist in your system.  However because Docker will fall over to the next range of 192.168 prefixes for new networks when the 172.16-31 space is full, that's why you have new networks with the 192.168 prefixes showing up.
Once the 192.168 space is exhausted, it'll fall over to 10.X.Y.0/24 ranges (where X and Y are numbers between 0 and 255) so you have a number of available ranges still.
Note that docker compose spins different bridges for each unique compose project so its less a limit of number of containers and instead the number of networks created. You can always specify network definitions in docker compose files to use more narrow ranges if you know what you're doing thus making more network segments of smaller size available for Docker's use.

thanks so there is quite a low upper limit for the number of docker containers we can have before it interferes with our own network

@bilogic the logic is actually smart and won't trample on your existing network. It'll skip that octet and prefix. Once 192.168 is used it'll start using 10.X.Y.0/24 subnets. (where X and Y are independent values between 0 and 255) And skip over known/mapped routes already in your routes table on-system.

Is that documented anywhere I can read? I did declare a static route on the docker host, but it was not prioritized

@bilogic Without your configuration it'll be impossible to answer, but no the logic of how things just fail over to other network ranges is the nature of private network segment allocations.

I added my static route AFTER docker containers were running, that might be why docker was not aware of my subnet and stepped on it.

@bilogic correct, if the network is already created by Docker, you're going to have static routes, etc. trampled on.  Note that it might still try and trample on the routes, it's supposed to bypass any known routes and network allocations on the system running Docker, but it might fail, in which case you just have to adjust the config for those bridges to other subnets.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network, the private network range is 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255
I don't know why there is no 172.16.0.0, but apart from this, the 172 range is used up.
